# Angular função global

Tags: angularjs

Bom dia rapaziada, não trabalho muito com front-end e comecei a usar o angular  com bootstrap a pouco tempo minha duvida é seguinte: tenho uma div para apresentação de mensagens, erro, sucesso; Para mudar mudar essas mensagens de acordo com os dados obtidos acabei por criar duas funções uma para sucesso e outra para erro onde é passado o $scope, $timeout e mensagem propriamente dita por parâmetro e essas funções são globais, para serem reutilizadas em outros controllers, isso está correto? Senão qual melhor maneira de faze-lo, seguem as funções:

```
/*Mensagens para operações realizadas com sucesso */
function showMsgSuccess($scope, $timeout, msg){
    $scope.mostraMsg = true;
    $scope.classMessage = 'alert alert-info default';
    $scope.message = msg;
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.classMessage = 'alert alert-info fade';
    }, 4000);       
}

/*Mensagens para operações realizadas com erro */
function showMsgError($scope, $timeout, msg){
    $scope.mostraMsg = true;
    $scope.classMessage = 'alert alert-danger default';
    $scope.message = msg;
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.classMessage = 'alert alert-danger fade';
    }, 4000);       
}
```

exemplo de chamada no callback

```
showMsgError($scope, $timeout, 'Erro ao Buscar Cep!!!');
```

o html

```
<div ng-if="mostraMsg" ng-class="classMessage">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign">  <strong>{{message}}</strong></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Boa noite amigo, eu recomendaria construir diretivas. ex.: <app-msg  error|success >Erro ao buscar Cep!</app-msg>. Algo similar a isso. Dá uma olhada no link. [https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component]. Qualquer dúvida só chamar